# Creating a Graph in Python

Tags: python

My goal is to take an input file that looks like the following:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% %%        % %      %
%    %%%%%% % %%%%%% %
%%%%%%     P  %      %
%    % %%%%%% %% %%%%%
% %%%% %         %   %
%        %%% %%%   % %
%%%%%%%%%%    %%%%%% %
%.         %%        %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

and create a graph structure that allows me to do searches to find the path from "P" to ".". I have attached below the code I currently have to do this. Basically I have create a 2D list of characters holding the input of the maze. I then have functions to find the starting and ending indices, as well as Node class to hold the nodes. In this case the blank spaces would all be potential nodes.

My primary question is, how do I begin creating the nodes to do say a BFS. Do I go to P and starting creating nodes and branching it out from it, or do I need some structure to hold all possible nodes? Also, do I have enough info to perform these searches in my node class? Any advice as to what my next step should be (without giving me the answer) would be greatly appreciated.

```
import StringIO
import sys
class Node:
 def __init__(self, state, path_cost):
    self.state = state
    self.parent = None
    path_cost = path_cost
 def get_cost():
    return self.path_cost
 def get_state():
    return self.state
 def get_parent():
    return self.parent

# turn the maze input into a 2D list of characters
def parse_input():
  fname = sys.argv[1] # get the input maze file
  with open(fname) as f:
      content = [list(line[:-1]) for line in f]
  return content

def find_location(maze, c):
 for i, x in enumerate(maze):
     if c in x:
         return(i, x.index(c))

def find_end(maze):
return find_location(maze, '.')

def find_start(maze):
return find_location(maze, 'P')

maze = parse_input()
print(find_end(maze))
print(find_start(maze))
```

Comment: you don't necessarily need more structure than you already have. What you can do here is simply define a `neighbors(point)` function that returns a list of coordinates for points next to the point that are spaces. Then use that function to visit neighbors, keep a list of your path and a set of visited coordinates, and you can implement your BFS

Comment: It looks (to me) like you have a "graph" in the data-structure sense of the word.  Nodes are places that have a `' '` in the input.  Vertices show which nodes are connected.  Then you use a pathfinding algorithm (simplest is probably Dijkstra) to get the optimal path.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys, it makes a lot more sense! It looks like I don't really need to use the Node class I made for this